# add placemarker in maps

Tags: java

I want to add a placemarker in maps using JSP.
How can I do that?

Which function is used for it?

Comment: More details would be helpful.  What kind of maps are you using?  What have you got so far?  If you could show some code, that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes you can.

However, the answer will depend on the map display technology you are using.  Check out the documentation for whatever that technology is, and it will give you the specifics.  Then just write your JSP accordingly.

---

If you are really using the Java Google Maps API from GDATA, then [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingFeatures) describes how to create a feature on a map in Java.  There is an example of creating a placemarker.

Comment: What map library are you talking about?

Comment: i am using java GDATA Client library.
there is any function createPlacemark() in this library???